# I get error on phone but on emulator it works fine

Tags: android, android-emulator

i'm getting an error when i run an app on my phone but when i start it via emulator it works fine. Emulator runs on same 2.1 froyo as my phone.

The error i get is

```
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

The problem happens in this code:

```
    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list, null);
```

When i try to inflate this view. Btw in my xml code is evrything ok, otherwise it wouldn't work on emulator either.

But if u think it my help here it is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_seznam" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="17dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif" >
        </TextView>         
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingLeft="17dp"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif" >

        </TextView>            

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_distance"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:textColor="#3b5688"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif" >

        </TextView>            



        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"
            android:src="@drawable/naprej" />


    </TableRow>


    </TableLayout>
```

edit: btw, it's the same if i use this:

```
   LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list, null);
```

Comment: Post the whole stack trace please

Comment: sorry i dont totaly undesrtand how this is done :S

Comment: you just put  `Error inflating class <unknown>`, please post the other lines of the logcat.

Comment: i coppied this line from error.tostring(), in my logcat is a lot of lines so i dont know which are helpful...

Comment: i got filling that the problem is in this lines of logcat they are often repeated 08-08 10:23:46.999: E/libgps(173): onUnsol: cmd 0x04 plen 57
08-08 10:23:46.999: E/libgps(173): oem_unsol_gps_measurement: num_sv 0
08-08 10:23:46.999: E/libgps(173): oem_unsol_gps_measurement: used_in_fix_mask 0000014E

Comment: Just paste all the red lines, it should be about 20 lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!!!!

I'was trying difreent things and it ended up, the whole problem was that there was a problem with my image bg_seznam. I don't know excactly why but somehow it was to small. I had it in xhdpi folder. All i did was to resize it to twice the normal and now it works like a charm.

Tenx for help CFlex, without ur's idea about logcat i wouldn't make it!